# Problemas con la instalación CDN de Bootstrap 4

Tags: jquery, bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Estoy empezando a trabajar con Bootstrap 4 y presento un inconveniente para usar los plugins. Con bootstrap 3 yo descargaba los archivos (boostrap.min.css, jquery, bootstrap.min.js) y los llamaba en el HTML, pero con Bootstrap 4 estoy tratando de hacer lo mismo y cuando pongo los CDN desde la URL publicada en el sitio web oficial de bootstrap, me inician sin ningún problema los plugins, pero cuando trato de hacerlo con los archivos descargados en mi computadora (localmente) no me funciona. Alguien podría decirme, por qué sucede esto?

Comment: Hola @Charlie podrías colocar un screenshot de la consola de tu navegador porque asi por asi nadie podra ayudarte. saludos

Comment: Porque casi seguro estás indicando mal la ruta de los archivos. Además, para qué los quieres usar en local, si existen en línea y tendrás la garantía de tenerlos siempre actualizados?

Answer (score 1):

Hola @Charlie debes revisar si están bien ubicadas tus rutas por ejemplo: 
 
Si tienes una carpeta de css y js y están al mismo nivel de index 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí] 
Entonces los archivos css lo colocarías así:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Y los archivos javascript así

```
<script src="./js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="./js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Si después de haber realizado esto no carga entonces sería un problema con el caché del navegador, para solucionar esto presiona Ctrl+F5 y con esto debería cargar correctamente.
 
Fuente: Experiencia propia 
 
Imagen: Visual Studio Code